# How can I get device id for push notifications using firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I found this solution and I think it is not the ID which is required for notification kindly tell me by some samples:

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String androidIdd = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

I guess I don't need an android id. I just want to get the device unique ID for Firebase Notification or GCM.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the guides on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in order to better understand your question and provide you with even better answers.

Comment: Thnx for guiding me paul karam

Comment: It's pretty clear from the documentation. Just follow the step by step guide and you'll be fine https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Answer (score 15):

Instead of using some third party tutorials I would prefer to take a look into the official [Firebase Cloud Messaging documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client).

If you have set up everything correctly you can just scroll to the topic

> Retrieve the current registration token
>
> When you need to retrieve the current token, call `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()`. This method returns null if the token has not yet been generated.

In a nutshell: Call `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` to reveive the current device token.

### EDIT:

The command `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` is deprecated. The same documentation mentions a new approach as below:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                    return;
                }

                // Get new Instance ID token
                String token = task.getResult().getToken();

            }
        });
```